# How to run multiple scripts from a script in python

Tags: python

I have 3 Python scripts, script1, script2 and script3 in a folder. I want to run script2 and script3 using script1. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: `import script2` `script2.main()` (if you defined a `main()` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In script1 you need to import script2 and script3:

At the top of script1:

```
import script2
import script3
```

To run a function from script2 for example:

```
script2.function()
```

You may also need to add a blank file called `__init__.py` in the same directory as the scripts, so that python can see that the directory is a library.

Comment: I tried import script2 but am getting an error that the module is not found.

Comment: In my original post the _ was missing from the init file name. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: The file should be called `__init__.py` with 2 underscores before and after `init`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    execfile("script2.py")
    execfile("script3.py")
```

or

```
    subprocess.call("script2.py")
    subprocess.call("script3.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use os.system:

```
os.system("script2.py")
os.system("script3.py")
```